# Drawing a truncated cone delimited by two node shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a network described by two graph layers, where in both layers I have to draw a different graph. Each level describes a different abstraction level, where one could be expanded into more components, as in the following code, where Firms contains Firma1 and Firma2.

```
% Interaction diagram
% Author: Pascal Seppecher
% Based on diagram from Marco Miani.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: Interaction diagram
:Tags: Scopes,3D, Diagrams,Transparency,Economics,Computer Science
:Author: Pascal Seppecher
:Slug: interaction-diagram

Real and monetary flows in an agent-based 
macroeconomic model with endogenous money.
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\MonetaryLevel}{Monetary level}
\newcommand{\RealLevel}{Real level}
\newcommand{\Firms}{Firms}
\newcommand{\Households}{Households}
\newcommand{\Banks}{Banks}
\newcommand{\Commodities}{Commodities}
\newcommand{\LaborPower}{Labor power}
\newcommand{\Wages}{Wages}
\newcommand{\Consumption}{Consumption}
\newcommand{\Credits}{Credits}
\newcommand{\Withdrawals}{Withdrawals}
\newcommand{\Deposits}{Deposits}
\newcommand{\Repayments}{Repayments}

\newcommand{\yslant}{0.5}
\newcommand{\xslant}{-0.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1,every node/.style={minimum size=.1cm},on grid]

    % Real level
    \begin{scope}[
        yshift=-120,
        every node/.append style={yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant},
        yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant
    ] 
        % The frame:
        \draw[black, dashed, thin] (0,0) rectangle (7,7); 
        % Agents:
        \node[fill=red,draw=black,label=above:\textbf{firma1}] at (3,3) (a) {};
        \node[fill=red,draw=black,label=above:\textbf{firma2}] at (5,3) (b) {};
        \node[ellipse,fit=(a) (b), fill=red,draw=black, opacity=0.5] (c) {};
    \end{scope}

    % 2 vertical lines for linking agents on the 2 levels
    \draw[ultra thin](3.8,4) to (c.west);
    \draw[ultra thin](3.8,4) to (c.east);

    % Monetary level
    \begin{scope}[
        yshift=0,
        every node/.append style={yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant},
        yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant
    ]
        % The frame:
        \fill[white,fill opacity=.75] (0,0) rectangle (7,7); % Opacity
        \draw[black, dashed, thin] (0,0) rectangle (7,7); 
         % Agents:
        \draw [fill=red]
            (5,2) circle (.1) % Firms
            (2,2) circle (.1) % Households
            (3.5,5) circle (.1); % Banks
         % Monetary Flows:
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (3.65,5.1) to[out=30,in=30] (5.15,2.1); % Credits
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (5,1.8) to[out=-90,in=-90] (2,1.8); % Wages
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (1.9,2.1) to[out=150,in=150] (3.4,5.1);  % Deposits
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (3.6,4.9) to[out=-30,in=-30] (2.1,1.9); % Withdrawals
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (2,2.2) to[out=90,in=90] (5,2.2); % Consumption
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (4.85,1.9) to[out=210,in=210] (3.35,4.9) ; % Repayments
         % Labels:
        \fill[black]
            (0.5,6.5) node[right, scale=.7] {\MonetaryLevel}
            (5.1,1.9) node[right,scale=.7]{\textbf {\Firms}}
            (1.9,1.9) node[left,scale=.7]{\textbf {\Households}}
            (3.5,5.1) node[above,scale=.7]{\textbf {\Banks}}
            (5.5,2.8) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=-100] {\Credits}
            (2.6,1.3) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=-10] {\Withdrawals}
            (2.9,4.25) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=50] {\Repayments}
            (2.6,5) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=25] {\Deposits}
            (4.7,2.9) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=-60] {\Consumption}
            (2.3,1.3) node [below, scale=.6, rotate=-40] {\Wages}; 
    \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The two nodes, Firma1 (node `a`) and Firma2 (node `b`), are contained inside another node (node `c`). In order to remark the containment relation, I would like to draw a truncated cone delimited by node `c` and Firms. Is there a way to do it without defining the explicit coordinates between the two and giving a tridimensional aspect to it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calc` library offers the `tangent` coordinate system:

```
\node[circle, draw] (a);
\coordinate (b) at (5,5);
\draw (b) -- (tangent cs:node=a,point={(b)},solution=1);
```

Draws a line from `(b)` to its respective tangent point in the circle delimited by the circle around `(a)`. We can use this in your drawing, but we need to have all nodes previously defined so we have to make the `Firms` circle as a node, no problem there. Then, after the all the necessary nodes have been defined we can call:

```
\draw[ultra thin](c.east) to (tangent cs:node=firms,point={(c.east)},solution=1);
\draw[ultra thin](c.west) to (tangent cs:node=firms,point={(c.west)},solution=2);
```

You could wonder if it's not possible to calculate the tangent points for both circles, and it is. *But*, the node `(c)` is no circle, then we get the error `I do not know how to calculate the tangent point for an ellipse`. Also since the drawing is at the end its done on the front layer and the line is not on the back of the Real level.

We mustn't worry, the `backgrounds` library is our friend. Also, if you compile with the previous solution you'll see that the `(c.west)` and `east` are not actual tangent points so we have to manually fix that, fortunately I got it right on the second guess:

```
\scoped[on background layer]{
  \draw[ultra thin](c.-10) to (tangent cs:node=firms,point={(c.-10)},solution=1);
  \draw[ultra thin](c.150) to (tangent cs:node=firms,point={(c.150)},solution=2);
};
```

### MWE:

(notes: must add the calc and background libraries in your original code, as well as make the red Firms circle as a node and have node `c` with `outer sep=0pt`)

```
% Interaction diagram
% Author: Pascal Seppecher
% Based on diagram from Marco Miani.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,calc,backgrounds}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: Interaction diagram
:Tags: Scopes,3D, Diagrams,Transparency,Economics,Computer Science
:Author: Pascal Seppecher
:Slug: interaction-diagram

Real and monetary flows in an agent-based 
macroeconomic model with endogenous money.
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\MonetaryLevel}{Monetary level}
\newcommand{\RealLevel}{Real level}
\newcommand{\Firms}{Firms}
\newcommand{\Households}{Households}
\newcommand{\Banks}{Banks}
\newcommand{\Commodities}{Commodities}
\newcommand{\LaborPower}{Labor power}
\newcommand{\Wages}{Wages}
\newcommand{\Consumption}{Consumption}
\newcommand{\Credits}{Credits}
\newcommand{\Withdrawals}{Withdrawals}
\newcommand{\Deposits}{Deposits}
\newcommand{\Repayments}{Repayments}

\newcommand{\yslant}{0.5}
\newcommand{\xslant}{-0.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1,every node/.style={minimum size=.1cm},on grid]

    % Real level
    \begin{scope}[
        yshift=-120,
        every node/.append style={yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant},
        yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant
    ] 
        % The frame:
        \draw[black, dashed, thin] (0,0) rectangle (7,7); 
        % Agents:
        \node[fill=red,draw=black,label=above:\textbf{firma1}] at (3,3) (a) {};
        \node[fill=red,draw=black,label=above:\textbf{firma2}] at (5,3) (b) {};
        \node[ellipse,fit=(a) (b), fill=red,draw=black, opacity=0.5,outer sep=0] (c) {};
    \end{scope}

    % Monetary level
    \begin{scope}[
        yshift=0,
        every node/.append style={yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant},
        yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant
    ]
        % The frame:
        \fill[white,fill opacity=.75] (0,0) rectangle (7,7); % Opacity
        \draw[black, dashed, thin] (0,0) rectangle (7,7); 
         % Agents:
        \draw [fill=red]
            (5,2) node[circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.2cm, draw, fill, name=firms,node contents={}] % Firms
            (2,2) circle (.1) % Households
            (3.5,5) circle (.1); % Banks
         % Monetary Flows:
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (3.65,5.1) to[out=30,in=30] (5.15,2.1); % Credits
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (5,1.8) to[out=-90,in=-90] (2,1.8); % Wages
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (1.9,2.1) to[out=150,in=150] (3.4,5.1);  % Deposits
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (3.6,4.9) to[out=-30,in=-30] (2.1,1.9); % Withdrawals
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (2,2.2) to[out=90,in=90] (5,2.2); % Consumption
        \draw[-latex, thin]
            (4.85,1.9) to[out=210,in=210] (3.35,4.9) ; % Repayments
         % Labels:
        \fill[black]
            (0.5,6.5) node[right, scale=.7] {\MonetaryLevel}
            (5.1,1.9) node[right,scale=.7]{\textbf {\Firms}}
            (1.9,1.9) node[left,scale=.7]{\textbf {\Households}}
            (3.5,5.1) node[above,scale=.7]{\textbf {\Banks}}
            (5.5,2.8) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=-100] {\Credits}
            (2.6,1.3) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=-10] {\Withdrawals}
            (2.9,4.25) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=50] {\Repayments}
            (2.6,5) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=25] {\Deposits}
            (4.7,2.9) node [above, scale=.6, rotate=-60] {\Consumption}
            (2.3,1.3) node [below, scale=.6, rotate=-40] {\Wages}; 
    \end{scope}

    % 2 vertical lines for linking agents on the 2 levels
    \scoped[on background layer]{
    \draw[ultra thin](c.-10) to (tangent cs:node=firms,point={(c.-10)},solution=1);
    \draw[ultra thin](c.150) to (tangent cs:node=firms,point={(c.150)},solution=2);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]